# Can I use a specific service that runs in Windows XP on a Windows 7 OS?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, services

I have a service running on Windows home server on a headless hp mediasmart server.  I believe the service, by virtue of running, turns a hardware "health" light from blinking to steady and turns on the drive lights.  OEM software was installed with their unique service.  The problem is that HP got out of the Windows home server market.  I've upgraded the box to WHS 2011, which is Windows 2008 r2/Window 7 esq.  So if I could somehow figure out where the bin/executable is and extract it, would it work on a Windows 7 OS?

Comment: The original Home Server is based on Server 2003 not XP.

Comment: That service is most likely unique to the HP hardware.

Comment: Check HP's driver site for your particular machine.  They might have it available for download.

Comment: @edusysadmin and Server 2003 was built together with XP.  Same OS, different features.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not.  It depends on the exact detail of what this service is doing and how it's interacting with the hardware.  I wouldn't hold out a lot of hope; a lot of the mechanics of security for services changed in Vista/7 (and presumably Server 2008), so you'll probably need a new version from the manufacturer that takes the new environment into account.